# Record of Disputation of Paris

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, christianity

Is the record of the disputation of Paris that took place in 1240, I believe called sefer havikuach, available for free online?

Comment: See [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/natsrut/yehiel-2.htm) and [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31982). (Similar question about the Ramban's later debate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53064).

Comment: I'm not sure that [tag:machlokes] applies here (this wasn't a disagreement between two equally valid sides), so I left it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the links provided in [J.C. Salomon's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/57246), there is an HTML page with a very readable typed and color coded version of ויכוח רבנו יחיאל מפריס on the Daat website [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/natsrut/yehiel-2.htm).

Answer (score 5):

HebrewBooks.org has the 1873 Thorn printing of [ויכוח רבנו יחיאל מפריס *Vikuach Rabeinu Yechiel meParis*](http://hebrewbooks.org/38584) ([alternate scan](http://hebrewbooks.org/43699)), and the 1928 Lwów (= Lvov = Lemberg) printing, [ויכוח רבנו יחיאל מפאריז](http://hebrewbooks.org/31982) ([alternate scan](http://hebrewbooks.org/20701)).

Comment: Wrong text: Ramban's vikuach is of the Barcelona disputation.

Comment: You're right: the Paris disputation was with R' Yechiel of Paris. More research needed.

Comment: Please remove this answer for as noted it refers to the Barcelona disputation rather than the Paris disputation. Interesting to hear Christiani's version though.